# Python import variables from sys.argv

Tags: python, variables, sys

I have a script like this

```
x = sys.argv[1]
y = sys.argv[2]
```

Sor when I run

```
python test.py 5 6
```

X is 5 and y is 6

Now I want to import x and y to another script like

```
from test import x, y
print x
```

I get an out of index error.  How can I import those variables?

Comment: Are you also running your other script like `python myOtherScript.py 5 6`? If not, what do you expect x and y to be?

Comment: No just run python other program python other.py and I expect just 5 and 6

Comment: Running `test.py` once with command-line arguments won't cause it to "remember" those values the next time you import it. `sys.argv` sees nothing but the parameters you specified when you ran the current program.

Comment: I see.  So is there a way i can set the vars so i can export them?